# Whenever I call this function Unity doesn't respond anymore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I always have to close Unity through Task-Manager if I call this function through a button, what is wrong with my code? I know there are is a lot of processing required for this code but the process never finishes:

```
public void SudokuLösen()
    {
        for(int p = 1; p < 81; p++)
        {
            if(PositionWert[p] != 0){
            for(int z = 1; z < 9; z++)
            {
                if(PositionWert[p] == z)
                {
                    int Reihe = 0;
                    int Spalte = 0;
                    int Platz = 0;
                    for(int m = 0; m < 8; m++)
                    {
                        for(int r = 1; r < 9; r++)
                        {
                            if(p - m * 9 == r)
                            {
                                Reihe = r;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    for(int s = 0; s < 9; s++)
                    {
                        if(p == Reihe * 9 - 9 + s )
                        {
                            s = Spalte;
                        }
                    }
                    for(int g = -8; g < 8; g++)
                    {
                        if((Spalte + g > 0) && (Spalte + g < 10))
                        {
                            Blockiert[(p + z * 81 - 81) + g] = true;
                        }
                        if((Reihe + g > 0) && (Reihe + g < 10))
                        {
                            Blockiert[(p + z * 81 - 81) + g * 9] = true;
                        }
                    }
                    for(int vx = 1; vx < 3; vx++)
                    {
                        if((Spalte == 0 + vx) || (Spalte == 3 + vx) || (Spalte == 6 + vx))
                        {
                            Platz += vx;
                        }
                        if((Reihe == 0 + vx) || (Reihe == 3 + vx) || (Reihe == 6 + vx))
                        {
                            Platz += (3 * vx - 3);
                        }
                    }
                    for(int q = 1; q < 4; q++)
                    {
                        Blockiert[(p + z * 81 - 81) + Quadrat[Platz * 4 - 4 + q]] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the Arrays are defined like this:

```
public static bool[] Blockiert = new bool[730];
public static int[] PositionWert = new int[82];
private int[] Quadrat = {0, 10, 11, 19, 20, 8, 10, 17, 19, 7, 8, 16, 17, -8, -7, 10, 11, -10, -8, 8, 10, -11, -10, 7, 8, -17, -16, -8, -7, -19, -17, -10, -8, -20, -19, -11, -10};
```

I thought that it might just be because my computer would just take forever to call this function so I waited a long time and saw that Unity nearly used 15% of my CPU so it didn't really do much and the function processing just doesn't finish.

Does anyone know what is wrong or what I should change?

Comment: it might take very long but it should finish. Attach visual studio and pause the execution to check if it is still running. You can also use breakpoints. Check the documentation [Debugging C# code in Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html)

Comment: ok, if so then what should I change to make it faster because this should not take long

Comment: I'm seeing reassignments to your loop index at`s = Spalte;`. Do you think you have an infinite loop? Please include a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A freeze usually means you have a never ending loop somewhere.

All your loops are finite and there is nothing that should take longer than a couple of milliseconds - **except one**!

You have

```
for(int s = 0; s < 9; s++)
{
    if(p == Reihe * 9 - 9 + s)
    {
        s = Spalte;
    }
}
```

where you reassign `s = 0` since `Spalte` was never assigned differently. So you restart the loop and if this condition is met once then it will definitely be met in a future iteration as well since none of the other parameters change within that loop => never ending loop.

Judging from the rest of your code it should probably rather be

```
Spalte = s;
```